# random_configuration_model(N,E) takes to long on LightGraphs.jl

Tags: time, julia, lightgraphs

I'm facing problems with the generation of configurational graphs on LightGraphs. Hereafter, the vector  `E` contains the sequence of edges. I have to generate this kind of graph iteratively inside a loop and the example below reproduces the problem.

```
using LightGraphs, Distributions
N=2000;c=0.01*N
α=0.625
p = α/(c+α)
E = zeros(Int64,N)

for j in 1:100
    s=0
    for i in 1:N
        E[i] = rand(NegativeBinomial(α,p))
        s += E[i]
    end
    if iseven(s) == false
        k = rand(DiscreteUniform(1,N))
        E[k] += 1
    end
    @show s
    g = random_configuration_model(N,E)
    @show j
end
```

At some iteration step `j`, it seems that `g = random_configuration_model(N,E)` takes unexpected (very) long time to run, since the variables that determine the complexity (`N` and `c`) remain of the same order. Making sure that the sequence is graphical with check_graphical=true doesn't help and the problem also happens. It happens only for small values of `α` (<1), but this parameter only affects the variance of the negative binomial distribution, and not its mean value, that is approximately `c` for finite `N`. Does anyone know something that may be causing this problem?

Edit: as a matter of completeness, I leave below how I generated the configuration random graph with iGraph (full doc: https://igraph.org/). One can find how to transform the iGraph object `g2` to a LightGraph object (and more on general usage) at [this](https://bkamins.github.io/julialang/2021/04/09/igraph.html) tutorial by Bogumił Kamiński.

```
using LightGraphs, PyCall, Distributions
ig = pyimport("igraph")

s=0;N=1000;c=N*0.01;α=0.625;p=α/(c+α)
E=zeros(Int64,N)
for i in 1:N
    E[i] = rand(NegativeBinomial(α,p))
    s += E[i]
end

if iseven(s) == false
    k = rand(DiscreteUniform(1,N))
    E[k] += 1
end

g2 = ig.Graph.Realize_Degree_Sequence(E)
```

Comment: LightGraphs is not being development anymore. All code from that package has been moved over to https://github.com/JuliaGraphs/Graphs.jl and development continues there.
For more information see also this post: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/lightgraphs-jl-transition/69526/17.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that `random_configuration_model` uses a rejection sampling approach to generate graphs.

You can already see it on quite star on 25 nodes:

```
julia> @time random_configuration_model(25, [24; fill(1, 24)])
 14.668509 seconds (134.34 M allocations: 16.465 GiB, 10.71% gc time)
{25, 24} undirected simple Int64 graph

julia> @time random_configuration_model(25, [24; fill(1, 24)])
  2.242426 seconds (20.41 M allocations: 2.501 GiB, 10.54% gc time)
{25, 24} undirected simple Int64 graph

julia> @time random_configuration_model(25, [24; fill(1, 24)])
 14.490126 seconds (130.53 M allocations: 15.999 GiB, 10.77% gc time)
{25, 24} undirected simple Int64 graph
```

Rejection sampling is problematic when degree sequence is almost non graphic (as then the probability to "hit" a simple graph is low).

Faster approaches than rejection sampling are available if you can accept a small deviation from uniform sampling but AFAICT are not implemented in Graphs.jl. One such method that is popular is https://arxiv.org/abs/cs/0502085 which additionally puts a restriction that the graph should be connected. This method is available in iGraph.