# Generating random configuration model graphs in Julia using iGraph

Tags: graph, julia, igraph

Recently I started to use iGraph in Julia to generate random configuration models, since LightGraphs has a problem with time realization of these objects (link to a previous question related to this: [random_configuration_model(N,E) takes to long on LightGraphs.jl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72732571/random-configuration-modeln-e-takes-to-long-on-lightgraphs-jl)). To generate such graphs, I generate a vector `E` (1-based indexed) and from it I generate an iGraph object `g2` as follows

```
using PyCall, Distributions
ig = pyimport("igraph")

α=0.625;N=1000;c=0.01*N;p=α/(α+c)
E = zeros(Int64,N)
test=false

while test == false
    s=0
    for i in 1:N
        E[i] = rand(NegativeBinomial(α,p))
        s += E[i]
    end
    if iseven(s) == true
        test = true
    else
    end
end

g = ig.Graph.Realize_Degree_Sequence(E)
```

My first question is related to the fact that python is 0-based indexed. By comparison of the components of `E` to the degrees of `g`, it seems that `ig.Graph.Realize_Degree_Sequence(E)` automatically convert the index bases, generating a 0 based object `g` from a 1-based object `E`. Is this correct?

Secondly, I would like to enforce the random configuration graph `g` to be simple, with no self loops nor multi-edges. iGraphs documentation (https://igraph.org/c/doc/igraph-Generators.html#igraph_realize_degree_sequence) says that the flag `allowed_edge_types:IGRAPH_SIMPLE_SW` does the job, but I am not able to find the syntax to use it in Julia. Is it possible at all to use this flag in Julia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading C docs of igraph. You need to read Python documentation https://igraph.org/python/api/latest/igraph._igraph.GraphBase.html#Degree_Sequence. So:

```
julia> ige = [collect(e .+ 1) for e in ig.Graph.Degree_Sequence(collect(Any, E), method="no_multiple").get_edgelist()];

julia> extrema(reduce(vcat, ige)) # OK check
(1, 1000)

julia> sg = SimpleGraph(1000)
{1000, 0} undirected simple Int64 graph

julia> for (a, b) in ige
           add_edge!(sg, a, b)
       end

julia> sg # OK check
{1000, 5192} undirected simple Int64 graph

julia> length(ige) # OK check
5192

julia> sort(degree(sg)) == sort(E) # OK check
true
```

I used `"no_multiple"` algorithm, as `"vl"` algorithm assumes connected graph and some of degrees of nodes in your graph can be 0.

Comment: Thank you, very much! So, you generate a collection of 2d vectors that symbolizes the edges from an iGraph object, than you map this object onto a LighGraphs object. From my trials, calculations with LightGraphs objects are faster than with iGraph objects. Is this why you perform this mapping?

Comment: I did this mapping because: a) I thought you wanted to use Graphs.jl for later analysis of the graph, b) you asked how to do the mapping between Python and Julia - and here all is done automatically except that the crucial part is that since Python is 0-based you need to add 1 to all vertex numbers as in Python they are numbered starting with 0 (and such mapping is not performed automatically).

Answer (score 3):

Be careful with LightGraph's `random_configruaton_model`. Last time I looked, [it was broken, and it did not sample uniformly](https://github.com/sbromberger/LightGraphs.jl/issues/1208), yet the authors outright refused to fix it. I don't know if anything changed since then.

C/igraph's [`degree_sequence_game()`](https://igraph.org/c/html/latest/igraph-Generators.html#igraph_degree_sequence_game) has a correctly implemented method that samples uniformly, called `IGRAPH_DEGSEQ_SIMPLE_NO_MULTIPLE_UNIFORM`, but for some reason it is not yet exposed in Python ... we'll look into exposing it soon.

Then you have two options:

- Use python-igraph's `"simple"` method, and keep generating graphs until you get a simple one (test it with `Graph.is_simple()`). This uses the stub-matching method, and will sample exactly uniformly. For large degrees, it will take a long time due to many rejections. Note that this rejection method exactly what the `IGRAPH_DEGSEQ_SIMPLE_NO_MULTIPLE_UNIFORM` implements (albeit bit faster).
- Use igraph's `Graph.Realize_Degree_Sequence()` to create one graph with the given degree sequence, then rewrite it using `Graph.rewire()` with a sufficiently large number of rewiring steps (at least several times the edge count). This method uses degree-preserving edge switches and can be shown to sample uniformly in the limit of a large number of switches.

The `"no_multiple"` method in python-igraph will again *not* sample uniformly.

Take a look at [section 2.1 of this paper](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/2632-072X/abced5#jpcomplexabced5s2) for a gentle explanation of what techniques are available for uniform sampling.

Comment: Quick heads up: the `IGRAPH_DEGSEQ_SIMPLE_NO_MULTIPLE_UNIFORM` method is now exposed in the `master` branch and it will be released with the next patch release: https://github.com/igraph/python-igraph/commit/b8e0c2117fec32e72cf253653fc20987bf0a33a6

Also, Szabolcs was kind enough to clarify the docs a bit: https://github.com/igraph/python-igraph/commit/e86e58917fa04bd7594679b1bf0b609a433829c5

Comment: I have seen the post of this discussion you presented about sampling with `random_configuration_model` on iGraphs, but I am still studying to understand the problem. Thank you for the answer and for the reference!